# Start and end times - how many concurrent events per hour/day/week etc

Tags: sql, algorithm, excel

I have a database of events like so:

Event Name, Start Date, Start Time, End Date, End Time

I need to find out the number of concurrent events (any overlapping events) per hour/day/week etc.

How can I go about this?

The data is currently in Excel, I tried some formula but found Excel just crashes with 10s of thousands of records so I can port this to an SQL database or any other suitable suggestion if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use a database or a standalone sort program or subroutine to pick out the start and stop events in ascending order of time and then process them with a simple program or routine.

As you read in events keep a running counter of open events - add one when you see a start and subtract one when you see a sort.

Then every time you pick up a new event you can work out how long it was since the last event, and you know how many events were open during this time. So if this was e.g. 5 minutes with two events open then you have seen 10 event-minutes of concurrent events.

If you total these event-minutes up and divide by the length of time from the first event to the last event you will have a measure of the average number of concurrent events - if you pick a random instant between the first and last event then the average number of concurrent events going on during that random instant will be this measure of average number of concurrent events.